# Using GDAL with Anaconda

Tags: python, gdal, installation, sentinel-2, anaconda

I want to read sentinel-2's image (jp2 format)  with anaconda:

- geopanda: for read shapefile
- folium (for create map in jupyter notebook ) (optional)
- gdal /osgeo : for read jp2 image

I follow this excellent tutorial:

https://medium.com/@chrieke/howto-install-python-for-geospatial-applications-1dbc82433c05

My problem is that geopandas and fiona, maybe folium are not compatible with gdal v3.0.0.

With this command : conda install gdal , gdal v3.0.0 is installed by defaut.

If you install geopanda, then gdal is downgraded, but gdal v2... does not read jp2 image.

If I do not install geopanda then I cannot read shapefile.

If I install geopanda after installing gdal, then gdal cannot read a jp2 image.

Is there any way to read the jp2 with gdal downgraded?

EDIT:
This is what anaconda does when I install geopandas

> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>
> geotiff-1.5.1-h6e819c3_4   proj-6.2.0-ha7a8c7b_1
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> pcre                 conda-forge::pcre-8.41-h6538335_1003 -->
>   pkgs/main::pcre-
>   8.43-ha925a31_0
>
> The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority
>   channel:
>
> gdal               conda-forge::gdal-3.0.1-py36h2fee047_9 -->
>   pkgs/main::gdal-
>   2.3.3-py36hdf43c64_0   geos                   conda-forge::geos-3.7.2-he025d50_2 --> pkgs/main::geos-
>   3.7.1-h33f27b4_0   icu                      conda-forge::icu-64.2-he025d50_1 --> pkgs/main::icu-5
>   8.2-ha66f8fd_1   libgdal             conda-forge::libgdal-3.0.1-haf49bb1_9 --> pkgs/main::libgd
>   al-2.3.3-h10f50ba_0   rasterio
>   conda-forge::rasterio-1.0.28-py36h261~ --> pkgs/main::raste
>   rio-1.0.21-py36h6bd7d87_0
>
> The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
>
> hdf5                           1.10.5-nompi_ha405e13_1103 -->
>   1.10.4-nompi_hcc 15c50_1106   kealib                               1.4.10-hf7dc31f_1005 --> 1.4.10-heacb130_ 1003   libnetcdf                             4.6.2-h376842a_1003 --> 4.6.2-h396784b_1 001   libspatialite                        4.3.0a-hee5a54d_1031 --> 4.3.0a-h6a0152f_ 1026

If I validate this choice, then jp2 driver is remove to the list gdalinfo --formats.

I need on the same platform of geopandas, gdal and rasterio.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I have **QGIS 3.82-Zanzibar** running against **GDAL/OGR** 2.4 and it perfectly read jp2 format. You can try with a little sample of a jp2 or geotiff raster and to observe if issues persist.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have Qgis Zanzibar and I want read jp2. But with anaconda, the issues persist. I do not know where the issues may come from. I tested several things, I really have no idea.

Comment: Yes, I know that but your issue with anaconda isn't with GDAL version. As I said before, you can try with a little sample of a jp2 or geotiff raster and to observe if issues persist or to use python interpreter in OSGEO Console to read these samples.

Comment: Have you seen this Q&A?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/214489/8104

Comment: Yes I seen, but it forces me to use a second gdal, outside of Anaconda platform. I edited my primary post with a list of package downgraded.